# Error código 500 en peticion POST en aplicacion .ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error500

Estoy intentando hacer una petición post desde una vista a mi controlador "Tienda" pero recibo como respuesta un código 500.
En este proyecto ya llevo varias vistas con diferentes peticiones (POST y GET) y no tengo problema con esos pero por alguna extraña razón cuando realizo esta petición, recibo esa respuesta inmediata.

**Este es el código que utilice en la vista**

```
 function MostrarMarca() {
            
            var _idcategoria = $("input[name=categoria]:checked").val()
            console.log(_idcategoria);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("ListarMarcaporCategoria", "Tienda")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ idcategoria: _idcategoria}),                
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "applicaction/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    

                    $("#contenedor_marca").LoadingOverlay("hide");

                    $("<div>").addClass("form-check").append(
                        $("<input>").addClass("form-check-input").attr({ "type": "radio", "name": "marca", "value": "0", "id": "mx", "checked": "checked" }),
                        $("<label>").addClass("form-check-label").text("Todos").attr({ "for": "mx" })
                    ).appendTo("#contenedor_marca")

                    $.each(response.data, function (i, element) {
                        $("<div>").addClass("form-check").append(
                            $("<input>").addClass("form-check-input").attr({ "type": "radio", "name": "marca", "value": element.IdMarca, "id": "m" + i}),
                            $("<label>").addClass("form-check-label").text(element.Descripcion).attr({ "for": "m" + i })
                        ).appendTo("#contenedor_marca")
                    })
                },             
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#contenedor_marca").LoadingOverlay("show");
                }

            })
        }
```

**En el controlador tengo el método que estoy llamando que recibe un parámetro**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ListarMarcaporCategoria(int idcategoria)
        {
            List<Marca> lista = new List<Marca>();

            lista = new CN_Marca().ListarMarcaporCategoria(idcategoria);

            return Json(new { data = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Utilizando las DevTools del navegador, en consola recibo este error
`POST https://localhost:44399/Tienda/ListarMarcaporCategoria 500`

Tambien en el preview desde el DevTool de la peticion POST recibo el siguiente mensaje
`Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'idcategoria' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL 'System.Int32' del método 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult ListarMarcaporCategoria(Int32)' en 'CapaPresentacionTIenda.Controllers.TiendaController'. Un parámetro opcional debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe declararse como parámetro opcional. Nombre del parámetro: parameters`

Estoy convencido que no es un problema con el codigo del metodo en el controlador ya que hice una prueba con Postman haciendo la misma peticion pasandole los mismos parametros y ahí si recibí la respuesta esperada:
[image]

**Asi se ve el contenido del body del mensaje POST desde el DevTool**

[image]

La verdad no entiendo porque no tengo el mismo comportamiento desde la aplicación.

Cualquier sugerencia sobre que podría fallar aquí sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya vi cual fue mi error, en el contentType "application" esta escrito como "applicaction"

Corrigiendo eso ya funciono todo bien